# R: Combine rows to multiple measurements

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a data table that I can then use for further analysis (i.e. to generate boxplots for instance).

The data I have been given looks like this (note the various numbers of measurements):

```
measurement_option, measurement
option1, 11.3
option1, 12.7,
option2, 19.3,
option2, 9.7
option2, 12.1
```

What I would like to do is get this

```
option1, 11.3, 12.7
option2, 19.3, 9.7, 12.1
```

I've seen people using `reshape` (though for that I would need a time variable, right?) and `cast`, but to be honest I couldn't get both commands to produce a list as shown above.

Comment: You need `aggregate`, not `reshape`, if you want to get your data in that form.

Comment: from what I have seen for ´aggregate´ I would need to specify an aggregation function - what function would I take for that since I don't want to aggregate the values, but actually the options? or am I missing something?

Comment: I've given an example as an answer, although I *really* don't think you would want your data in that format. Data in a "long" format is usually much easier to work with for further analysis than data in a "wide" format (which this isn't even....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do much more for a boxplot using ggplot.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = measurement_option, y = measurement)) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

should do what you want. See [the ggplot manual](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html) for details.

Comment: +1 This should be the right answer--the OP is just going to get into trouble if they convert their data into the aggregated format they are trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

As @LostBrit correctly points out, your data are already in the best format for plotting. For instance, assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", you can simply do:

```
boxplot(measurement ~ measurement_option, mydf)
```

If you really want your data in the format that you showed (but then, I have no clue how you would do further plots easily), the function you should actually be looking at is `aggregate`. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", you can use `as.vector` as the aggregation function:

```
> aggregate(measurement ~ measurement_option, mydf, as.vector)
  measurement_option     measurement
1            option1      11.3, 12.7
2            option2 19.3, 9.7, 12.1
```

Note, however, that "measurement" is now a `list`.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying! makes completely sense! and thanks for the example, though I'm not going to use it. but maybe someone might need it in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dt = fread('measurement_option,measurement
option1,11.3
option1,12.7
option2,19.3
option2,9.7
option2,12.1')

# or
# dt = data.table(your_data_frame)

dt[, list(list(measurement)), by = measurement_option]
#   measurement_option            V1
#1:            option1     11.3,12.7
#2:            option2 19.3,9.7,12.1
```